# How to find a Rotation Matrix given 2 rotated coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been looking at this question for a while now and have not found any success.

What is the rotation matrix that relates the coordinate systems in the figure below - given that ro2a^x1y1x1 = [6 8 10]T and ro2b^(x1y1x1) = [-6 -8 10]t (the o2a and o2b is subscript and x1y1x1 is superscript). Briefly explain how you derived such a matrix

Any help would be amazing, Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Erik... Dude... This question comes up every year! So how far are you through the CBEPS process anyway? LOL! Struggling with this typo-filled question from the C-7 Remote Sensing exam?? (How did I know?? Hahaha!)

That is certainly an interesting question, but "interesting" in a slap-myself-in-the-face kind of way.

I'll try to word my answer in a fashion that is less focused on generalized geometry and better focused on this specific CBEPS question. You are welcome to share this message with anyone who might benefit as they move forward through the CBEPS process.

First, a bit of background:

1. This photogrammetry question appears EVERY YEAR on the C-7 "remote sensing" exam. It is exactly the same every year, even including the two typos.
2. The question always includes two vectors in the form [ *a b c* ] and [ *-a -b c* ], where the *a* and *b* values flip sign from one vector to the other, while *c* holds the same sign. Sometimes *a*, *b*, and *c* are 3, 4, 5 and sometimes they're 6, 8, 10. These small changes are trivial -- The answer to the question is exactly the same, year after year.
3. The superscripts in both reference vectors are typed incorrectly. Year after year, they never fix this typo. The superscript specifies the coordinate frame, which should be x1 y1 **z1**, not x1 y1 **x1**. The designers of this exam are smart, picky people, yet they let this dumb typo persist year after year.
4. Each year, CBEPS candidates show up on various math/compsci discussion forums asking for help... and the help never comes.

With that background in mind, I'll share my thoughts on the common WRONG answer that comes up every year.

Incorrectly, people think the following 3x3 matrix does the trick:

```
-1   0   0 
 0  -1   0 
 0   0   1
```

#1) I'm happy to say that the answer is based on a solid intuition. Yes, indeed, the flipping of signs of the x and y values (while preserving the z value) would be achieved by either: (a) 180° rotation about the *z* axis, or (b) scaling both *x* and *y* values by -1. (Note that a negative scale factor has the effect of reflection.)

#2) Regardless of whether you choose the rotation or the reflections, the numbers work out the same. The reflection scaling is -1... The cosine of 180° is -1... whatever... It's all good. Either way, the resulting (correct) transformation matrix is:

```
-1   0   0   0
 0  -1   0   0
 0   0   1   0
 0   0   0   1
```

This matrix can be described as "a 4x4 matrix with zeros in upper and lower triangles and a trace of [ -1 -1 +1 +1 ]."

The first and second "-1" values represent a reflection in *x* and *y* values while the next "1" represents preserving *z* values unchanged.
Alternatively, the "-1" values represent multiplying cos(180°) by cos(0°) and the "1" represents  multiplying cos(0°) by cos(0°). Whatever... It's all the same deal, right?

#3) ---> [The point of this post!] <---
Students often provide this (incorrect) transformation matrix:

```
-1   0   0 
 0  -1   0 
 0   0   1
```

Yes, I see the intuitive appeal in the simplicity of this answer, but it is wrong for the following reason:

There are 15 parameters to a transformation in 3-space.
translate *x*,
translate *y*,
translate *z*,
scale *x*,
scale *y*,
scale *z*,
rotate around *x* axis,
rotate around *y* axis,
rotate around *z* axis,
shear *xy*,
shear *xz*,
shear *yz*,
projection *xy*,
projection *xz*, and
projection *yz*.

A math nerd would point out that these 15 parameters capture all possible "affine transforms" and "projection transforms," but would neglect any twisting transforms. That's okay -- There are no applications of twisting transforms in photogrammetry. (There are indeed some applications in computer graphics, but those 5x5 transformation matrices are not relevant to your average CBEPS candidate.)

Having said that, there certainly ARE applications of shearings and projections in photogrammetry.

In fact, not to put too fine of a point on it, *but*... I gotta say that I would be a little concerned about a student who is expected to understand photogrammetry, yet presents a 3x3 matrix as an adequate description of a photogrammetric transform.

Sure, it is true that a lot of land surveying transforms can be captured in a 3x3 matrix. This is the case only because land surveyors tend to "flatten" their data into N and E values, leaving all points on a 2-d mapping plane. **All 2-d transforms can be expressed with a 3x3 matrix.**

Photogrammetry, however, is necessarily a 3-d enterprise. A remote sensing student ought to know that **a 3-space transformation matrix CANNOT be completely expressed in a 3x3 matrix**. Any sensible answer to the C-7 question must be expressed as a 4x4 matrix.

I hope that you find good targets for this message -- I hope someone benefits from my grief over this question, typos and all, along with students' failure to realize that the **3-d affine transforms require a 4x4 matrix**.

But hey... For those students who don't care about photogrammetry, but just want to push through the C-7 and never use photogrammetry in their land surveying careers, then it all boils down to this single bit of advice:

The correct answer is this matrix:

```
-1   0   0   0
 0  -1   0   0
 0   0   1   0
 0   0   0   1
```

... along with some explanation about how "obviously the transformation is a 180° rotation about the z axis."

That was the correct answer this year... and last year... and the year before that... and the year before that...

... and that's what the correct answer will be when they give the same typo-filled question on the C-7 exam in 2022.

Buy hey... I'm just a first-year student at NAIT. I'm happy on those days when I remember how many legs are on a tripod!

Good luck on them 'zams!